# Redux Store Duplicates on Hot Reload

Tags: webpack, redux, webpack-dev-server

I have the following `store.ts`

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const reducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
  if (action.type === 'INC') {
    return state+1;
  }
  return state;
}

//Create a dummy store
export const store = createStore(reducer, 0);
```

It is mainly an example I was running through from a tutorial - A simple store with not much going on.

And then in my `component.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { store } from 'path/to/store';

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('store changed', store.getState());
})

store.dispatch({type: 'INC', payload: 1});
...
```

So when I load the page, I see in the console:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... 
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
store changed 1
```

Whenever I modify the `component.tsx` file, my `webpack-dev-server` reloads and then I see the following:

```
[WDS] App hot update...
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
store changed 2
store changed 2
```

So it seems that my store is persisting, which is fine, and I don't even actually mind that it changes to `2` from `1` (because there is a +1).

However I am concerned that it shows up twice, which sort of makes me think there is two instances now.

Is there a way around this or is this just an issue with hot reloading with redux stores?

I am using `webpack`, `webpack-dev-server`, `react-hot-loader`

Comment: can you show your entry point (normally index.js) which is, I assume, where you add a handler for `module.hot.accept`

Comment: This is the awkward part where I tell you that I don't have that?

Comment: What are you using for hot reloading? React Hot Loader?

Comment: Would recommend not using that if you're using redux as you don't care about local state. Have a look at this https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/1455 - redux's and React Hot Loader's original author's recommendation to just use webpack's built in HMR api. You can keep redux state as the store is defined outside the `module.hot.accept` callback so it persists even after the modules in the tree below `./App` are replaced - you keep the state :)

Comment: also I've got a basic HMR/redux/react demo project that's pretty straightforward if you want to take a look - to run the basic dev server it's just `npm run dev-server` after you install. https://github.com/will-ockmore/catbook/